# How to clear neovim buffer

Tags: terminal, vim

I have a terminal buffer with 10000 lines of previously executed output.
In order to search for the particular sequence of words I have to go through all 10000 lines before getting to my last executed command's output.
Which makes me so annoyed.
Is the a way of clearing a terminal buffer without quiting the terminal and running it again (because I use ssh to remote server and it's painfull to execute all the commands all over again to establish the connection to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tnoremap <C-l> <C-\><C-n>:call ClearTerminal()<cr>

function! ClearTerminal()
  set scrollback=1
  let &g:scrollback=1
  echo &scrollback
  call feedkeys("\i")
  call feedkeys("clear\<CR>")
  call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>")
  call feedkeys("\i")
  sleep 100m
  let &scrollback=s:scroll_value
endfunction
```

Comment: I try to run this function, but neovim tells me that s:scroll_value is undeclared, Why? My neovim version is 0.6.1.

Comment: @aszswaz Add this somewhere above the function definition 
 <br> <br>
```vim
let s:scroll_value = 3000
let &scrollback=s:scroll_value                 " Reset/clean terminal like, we can't scrollback upwards
```

Comment: let s:scroll_value = 3000  
  let &scrollback=s:scroll_value                 " Reset/clean terminal like, we can't scrollback upwards